# Getting a heavily nested class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class

I'm looking to getting a certain class that is deeply nested. This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#cal-day-box #cal-day-panel #cal-day-panel-hour .cal-day-hour .row-fluid, .cal-day-hour-part .span11, .col-xs-11').click( function() {
        console.log("success jquery");
        $(this).hide();
      });
```

The HTML hierarchy is as follows:

```
<div id="cal-day-box">
    <div id="cal-day-panel">
        <div id="cal-day-panel-hour">
            <div class="cal-day-hour">
                <div class="row-fluid cal-day-hour-part">
                    <div class="span11 col-xs-11">
</ ... div>
```

When I only use the first ID selector, the code works fine. It breaks somewhere along the way. No error is caught. The "success jquery" is not printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/L3sZb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('#cal-day-box #cal-day-panel #cal-day-panel-hour .cal-day-hour .row-fluid.cal-day-hour-part .span11.col-xs-11').click( function() {
```

The CSS for the last two divs needs to be `.row-fluid.cal-day-hour-part .span11.col-xs-11`.

When you target multiple classes in an element, you don't put spaces or commas between the classes. Commas are used for separating multiple selectors. Spaces are for selecting descendant elements.